Use your fingers!
This puzzle is my attempt to make one in the style of PSE user Prim3numbah:


Find what is in the question mark!
1D3, 12, ED, ED, 5A, 244, 84, 1E2, 1E2, ?

Go back a step and swap the 3rd and 4th to find out what just happened to the puzzle (4).
Hints:
1)

 The numbers point to a maybe not so familiar plotting system of a very familiar system. That familiar system is hinted at by the title. There is however a little twist - work out all the rebuses first to understand what I am talking about.





 For the top right rebus you could use  as the bottom picture. The familiar system is especially familiar to a very specific minority group of people.

Bigger hint:

 For the top right rebus YOU  could just be used instead, don’t overthink this one. For the string think DOTS!

Even bigger hint:

 Top left is not ‘52’ think again. The top right rebus is a homophone. The bottom right has no wordplay it is what it is. Also the ordering of the puzzle is important: work on the rebuses first! Then you would know what you need to do to the string of letters and numbers.


Note: I just edited this puzzle to make it a little more straightforward.

Note 2: I am going to edit this puzzle again to make it easier and to correct an error. I sincerely apologize for it.

I think I got the left part but can't make sense of the right part yet. Guess I have to get in to my own mind and see how I would think :)

I have an idea, that it's related to the rot13(qvtvgf),given the title, but not sure.

Just to save you time no that’s not it…

@Prim3numbah I just dropped a hint good luck

The left part of the rebuses spells:

 Base-7 (A substance with a pH value higher than 7 is considered Base)

Thanks to the astute observation of M Oehm, the top right rebus can be read as:

 ME + ROAR = MIRROR (phonetically). So we need to mirror something later on. The bottom right image shows a graph with the vertical axis highlighted in red, which indicates that we should mirror along the vertical axis.

Furthermore, based on the OP's hints and the title, it has become clear that

 some form of Braille is used.

To decode the string:

 We convert the numbers from base-16 to base-7.

 This gives the numbers:


 1235, 24, 456, 456, 156, 1456, 246, 1256, 1256, ?.


 This looks promising, because we don't see any duplicate digits within the numbers. Also, there are no 0's present and all numbers are ascending.
 Using Braille pattern dots notation, we get:


 ⠗⠊⠸⠸⠱⠹⠪⠳⠳.


 In itself, this string does not make a whole lot of sense.

But:

 If we mirror all individual Braille characters along the vertical axis, we get:

 ⠺⠑⠇⠇⠎⠏⠕⠞⠞

  WELLSPOTT

Finally:

 To complete the sentence, we should add ED. It took me a while to realize that there is a Braille contraction just for the combination ED: ⠫

 If we mirror that, we get the letter ⠝ (N) which is made up of the dot pattern 1345. Converting from base-7 back to base-16, we get 20B, which is what should be placed on the question mark!

OP’s edit:
For the final question

 The answer is ACED because when we go a step back and get 1345, we swap the last two digits and it becomes 1354 which leads to when converted into letters via A1Z26 cipher it results in it.


Notice that shoe?

I think the the top right rebus is rot13(ZVEEBE = ZR + EBNE. Vg unf fvk yrggref nf vaqvpngrq naq gur uvag tvif ENJ zrng nf na nygreangvir.). It's a hint to something you have already found out. And rot13(vs lbh gnxr RQ nf jubyr, lbh trg gur Oenvyyr yrggre Y). And I can imagine that the overall answer is the classic rot13(gur sbhe-yrggre jbeq ABRY - ab Y).

@MOehm Good observation, I will edit my answer. Thanks :)

@PDT The third and fourth are both ED or am I missing something?

Yes I saw them. I'm still trying to put the last piece in place, though I don't have much time for puzzling today. Will get back to it when I can.

@PDT Go back to which step? And swap the 3rd and 4th what? If characters in the original string, they are the same (both ED).

I edited the last part in as it was intended to be a cherry on top that people who got that far might find amusing, kinda like a bonus or Easter egg and you have taken too long and I am impatient.

@PDT Nice one! That was too difficult for me to spot, so thanks for filling it in.

Some initial thoughts:
The premise

 The title "Use your fingers", the hint "DOTS", and the hint "not so familiar plotting system well-known by a specific minority group" seem to be alluding to the Braille system.

The left portion of the rebus

 could be alluding to a basic 52-card deck (a pH higher than 7 indicates a basic pH, while the fingers are showing 5 and 2).

The upper right portion of the rebus

 could be the word "filthy"? A 6-letter reference to the quote "you filthy animal" from the movie Home Alone.

 Alternatively, "sapien", as this is the type of animal that the reader presumably is.

The sequence

 For the sequence of numbers/letters, perhaps we should draw them out in Braille? But I wasn't able to find a pattern here. Also, the characters for "e" and "5" are the same lol


You are right only in the first paragraph. But even there you haven’t quite worked out the plotting system I am thinking of. Nice try though.

Check the new hint! Good luck!
